# JSON Serializing and deserializing nested objects with pandas/numpy attributes

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy

Consider a set of nested objects like:

```
class Fighter:
    name: str
    games: pd.DataFrame
    home_arena: Arena
class Arena:
    name: str
    capacity: np.ndarray
    location: Coordinates
class Coordinates:
    latitude: float
    longitude: float
```

I would like to serialize a `Fighter` as a JSON to return it in a web service, and store it, including the data in its pandas/numpy objects, in a database in a programming-language neutral way. I would also like to reconstitute `Foo` as an object for later use.

What are my options? I have considered:

1. pickle - unreadable blob in database -- no good because i can't query access details of data attributes without instantiating the objects
2. jsonpickle - a little more readable still too blobby to use
3. write `to_json` method on Foo that recursively serializes the attributes non-destructively and `from_json` to deserialize. Though [pd.DataFrame.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and [numpy.ndarray.tolist](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) take care of the heavy lifting, connecting all the dots is still a chore.

Are there any existing solutions for a case like this? The requirements are human-readable JSONs all the way through (no blobs!) and non-destruction of the DataFrame--at least, up to a point. I can safely assume all of the actual DataFrame elements will be `float`, `str` or `int`, and nothing exotic like `MultiIndex`es. If not, any pointers on how to best accomplish this?

I'm envisioning an output like:

```json
{
    "name": "Joe",
    "games": {
        "game_id": [1, 2, 3],
        "opponent": ["Jane", "John", "James"]
    },
    "home_arena": {
        "name": "My Little Square Garden",
        "capacity": [5000, 10000, 20000],
        "location": {
            "latitude": 89.14564,
            "longitude": -132.15635
        }
    }
}
```

And usage like `assert Fighter() == deserialize(serialize(Fighter()))`